# getMaxInactiveInterval returns a different value than the value configured in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-timeout, httpsession

I have a SpringBoot application with session timeout being set in `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=2000
```

But when I check the value after a `HttpSession` has been created:

```
System.out.println("getMaxInactiveInterval: " + request.getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval());
```

This is printed:

```
getMaxInactiveInterval: 1980
```

Why is 2000 not printed, as configured?

I've tried a test whereby I do not set `server.servlet.session.timeout`, and `1800` is printed on the console. So I know my property is having some effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the container rounds the value.

E.g 2000 equals 33.33 minutes, so container rounded the value to 33 minutes which is 1980 seconds.